# Change caption text of slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am using **Slick Slider** for my image slideshow. For each slide I also have a caption with a data-attribute. I want that the information of this data will change with each slide in a div outside of my slideshow, but for any reason it will only show me the first data stored when I click through it.

**JS**

```
$('.category-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var title = $(".title").data("project");
    $(".project").text(title);
});
```

**HTML**

*This is my caption with the data:*

```
<div class="projectTitle sans-s">
    <p class="title" data-project="<?php echo $project->projecttitle();?>">
    <?php echo $project->projecttitle();?></p>
</div>
```

*The data should appear here for each slide:*

```
<div class="project"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make reference to the title specific to the slider like this

```
  $('.category-slider')
   .on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    var title = $(this).find(".title").data("project");
    $(".project").text(title);
  });
```